# Swift Error: The file “Dicee-iOS13” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, xcode10.1

I have Macbook Pro (Late 2011) 10.13.6 High Sierra

XCode Version 10.1

In order to run Swift 5 on my XCode I followed the steps on this link: https://learningswift.brightdigit.com/swift-5-0-xcode-10-1/

1) Download and Install the Swift 5.0 Development Branch Toolchain.

2) Create Your Project or Target in Xcode 10.1

3) Go to the Top Menu and Select Xcode…Toolchains… Swift 5.0 Snapshot…

4) Go to the Top Menu and Select File…Project Settings

5) Under Shared Project Settings section select Legacy Build System.

6) Go to Plugins in Content/Resources in .xcspec file and add 5.0 to SupportedLanguageVersions and Swift 5.0-dev to LanguageVersionDisplayNames.

Now I cloned a github project from appbrewery and the clone link is: https://github.com/appbrewery/Dicee-iOS13.git
and I get this error when I run the Dicee project:

**Build Succeeded** but then ....
**The file “Dicee-iOS13” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it**

I have cleaned my project and tried to change my build settings to different iOS versions and I have looked at my info.plist at my $(EXECUTABLE_NAME). Also I have checked to see where the project is saved what my permissions are and they are read and write.

I have debated whether to get MacinCloud and it could possibly solve all my problems but I would rather not unless it is absolutely necessary (if no one can help me).

Any help would be appreciated!